# How can I create a dynamic blob linked service?

Tags: sql, azure

I want to access multiple storage accounts. I want one sql table to be uploaded to one blob and other sql table to the other. for this, i have to use just one pipeline. How can I create a dynamic blob?

Answer (score 0):

Each storage account requires its own connection string.

One way to do this would be to create a service (for example an azure function) that you pipeline calls. In the function there is logic to place the the correct table in the correct storage account.

Comment: Can you help me out with this? I am actually new to azure